# How to order matrix elements so that the difference between sum of each two columns and each two rows are minimized?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, matrix

I have a 2D matrix (nxn) of elements. I want to order the elements such that:

1. If I look at the columns, the difference between the sum of the elements of each two columns are minimum.

AND

2. If I look at the rows, the difference between the sum of the elements of each two rows are minimum.

Example:

From:

`0  1  2 
3  4  5
6  7  8`

row #0, #1, #2: 3, 12, 21  ==> differences (#0, #1), (#0, #2), (#1, #2): 9, 18, 9

col #0, #1, #2: 9, 12, 15  ==> differences (#0, #1), (#0, #2), (#1, #2): 3, 6, 3

To:

`0  4  8
5  7  2
6  1  3`

row #0, #1, #2: 12, 14, 10 ==> differences (#0, #1), (#0, #2), (#1, #2): 2, 2, 4

col #0, #1, #2: 11, 12, 13 ==> differences (#0, #1), (#0, #2), (#1, #2): 1, 2, 1

(Not sure if this is the best order!)

I was wondering if there is any algorithm for it. I looked at the partition problems such as [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056592/minimizing-the-difference-between-sums) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_pseudo-polynomial_algorithm). The difference in my problem is that, I know that in each dimension (column or row), the number of elements in buckets are equal (n).

Comment: So you want both the columns and the rows sorted? What is your starting state and desired end state? Can you give an example?

Comment: @bstrain I tried to provide an example. Let me know if it is still not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Here is a link to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971898/minimize-sum-of-columns-in-matrix-by-permutating-elements-in-python